# recommenations for building one rails app to serve both desktop (regular) and mobile (ajax) site

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, mobile, desktop

I'm developing a site which has both a desktop and mobile version.

The desktop is a standard rails app with the views presenting the final content to the user.

The mobile version is an ajax one-page app where requests are made the to same rails controllers, but return json which the app uses knockout to manage the models in javascript and display the content to the user.

The templates that are being shown to the user in mobile should really be the same as the apps html desktop views (ruby), with the difference being changes managed through a css media query.

Right now, I have a templates directory in the asset pipeline for the mobile app, and views in the app/views folder for the desktop app.

I've been trying to find if there is a way to have the views from within the app/views folder be compiled in the asset pipeline?

Or has somebody else managed to do this another way? Any suggestions welcome.

Answer (score 0):

You should try twitterbootstrap. It is very awesome It is what I use.

All you need to do is just go to [Bootstrap](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/) and just follow their guides.

A rails gem is also available.

If you need more help, just ask for it and I will help